# Trouble with regex a value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am currently trying to mask an input field.I have the following code at the moment which formats the input:

```
    const inputMask = (value) => value.replace(/\s/g, '').match(/.{1,4}/g)?.join(' ').substr(0, 19) || '';
```

So i have an input field which calls the above function `inputMask` whenever a user is inputting a number.

I have input XXXXXXXXXXX into the text input

what gets returned is XXXX XXXX XXX from the inputMask function

what i am trying to achieve is XXX-XXXX-XXXX

Comment: What is the input value?

Comment: @0stone0 01211234567

Comment: So you're trying to remove the double `1` from the input?

Comment: no, i am trying to format my input to be XXX-XXXX-XXX

Comment: But those are 10 digits, and your input shows 11.....

Comment: using .join('-') works for me...


>'01211234567'.replace(/\s/g, '').match(/.{1,4}/g)?.join(' ').substr(0, 19)
"0121 1234 567"


>'01211234567'.replace(/\s/g, '').match(/.{1,4}/g)?.join('-').substr(0, 19)
"0121-1234-567"

Comment: Ive updated the question , i hope this makes more sense

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't. There are 11 chars in the input, but 10 in the ouput. Where did that single char go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const input = '0121234567'
const res = input.toString().replace(/(\d{3})(\d{4})(\d{3})/, '$1-$2-$3');
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `slice` and add dashes

```js
const input = '01211234567'
const inputMask = (value) => `${value.slice(0, 3)}-${value.slice(4, 8)}-${value.slice(8, 11)}`;
console.log(inputMask(input));
```

Regular expressions are not necessary.